# TypeScript Error in React Query Hook - getNextPageParam Issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, function, next.js, react-query

```
I'm encountering a TypeScript error in my React Query hook that involves the getNextPageParam function. I have a useInfiniteQuery hook defined as follows
export const useGetPosts = () => {
  return useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.GET_INFINITE_POSTS],
    queryFn: getInfinitePosts, 
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
      if(lastPage && lastPage.documents.length === 0) return null;

      const lastId = (lastPage?.documents[lastPage?.documents.length-1].$id);
      return lastId;
    }
  })
}
```

The error message I'm receiving is:

I tried using the function with the **`any`** type as a workaround, but it leads to errors in the entire function. Here is the modified version:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(options: UndefinedInitialDataInfiniteOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, QUERY_KEYS[], number>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseInfiniteQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(lastPage: DocumentList<Document> | undefined) => string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetNextPageParamFunction<number, DocumentList<Document> | undefined>'.
      Type 'string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | null | undefined'.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(options: DefinedInitialDataInfiniteOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, QUERY_KEYS[], number>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): DefinedUseInfiniteQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(lastPage: DocumentList<Document> | undefined) => string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetNextPageParamFunction<number, DocumentList<Document> | undefined>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(options: UseInfiniteQueryOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, DocumentList<...> | undefined, QUERY_KEYS[], number>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseInfiniteQueryResult<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '(lastPage: DocumentList<Document> | undefined) => string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetNextPageParamFunction<number, DocumentList<Document> | undefined>'.ts(2769)
queryClient-mVGWb1w6.d.ts(336, 5): The expected type comes from property 'getNextPageParam' which is declared here on type 'UndefinedInitialDataInfiniteOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, QUERY_KEYS[], number>'
queryClient-mVGWb1w6.d.ts(336, 5): The expected type comes from property 'getNextPageParam' which is declared here on type 'DefinedInitialDataInfiniteOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, QUERY_KEYS[], number>'
queryClient-mVGWb1w6.d.ts(336, 5): The expected type comes from property 'getNextPageParam' which is declared here on type 'UseInfiniteQueryOptions<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, Error, InfiniteData<DocumentList<Document> | undefined, unknown>, DocumentList<...> | undefined, QUERY_KEYS[], number>'
```

```
export const useGetPosts = () => {
  return useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: [QUERY_KEYS.GET_INFINITE_POSTS],
    queryFn: getInfinitePosts as any, 
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage: any) => {
      if(lastPage && lastPage.documents.length === 0) return null;

      const lastId = (lastPage?.documents[lastPage?.documents.length-1].$id);
      return lastId;
    }
  })
}
```

This modification results in errors throughout the entire function. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and properly handle the **`getNextPageParam`** function. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have all the answers in that error:
1: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'`
2: `Type '(lastPage: DocumentList<Document> | undefined) => string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetNextPageParamFunction<number, DocumentList<Document> | undefined>'.`
3: `Type '(lastPage: DocumentList<Document> | undefined) => string | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'GetNextPageParamFunction<number, DocumentList<Document> | undefined>'` so just debug the values that you are passing to that hook. Using `any` in Typescript is really bad practice.